# How to stop foreground bootstrap service of Android Beacon Library

Tags: ibeacon-android

I'm trying to use background startup of Android Beacon Library.
I'm using `regionBootstrap` class to notify my beacons proximity.

In Android Application class, I call `enableForegroundServiceScanning` method before to create new `regionBootstrap`, so, with Android 8+, I am able to receive notifications when my activity is killed too.

I'd like to stop the foreground library service if the user don't want this service anymore, but I don't understand how to do it. Somebody help me?

this my sample code:

```
    public class GlobalState extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            super.onCreate();

            beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
            beaconManager.setDebug(true);

            List<Region> rl = getPrefList();
            if (rl.size() > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning (m_builder.build(), 3);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Foreground service starting error: " + e);
                }
                regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, rl);
                Log.d(TAG, "Region scan set!");
            }
            else
            {
                beaconManager.disableForegroundServiceScanning();
                regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, rl);
                regionBootstrap.disable();
                Log.d(TAG, "Region scan disable...");
            }
        }
...
```

Comment: Show your [mcve] and show messages or errors. Make it clear what your question is. Hint: the question should not be in the title, or at least should be made clear in the text of the question. Update your question with an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

I used the "regionBootstrap.disable()" for stopping monitoring.

Comment: I'm using "regionBootstrap.disable()" too, it works fine on Android 6.x, but I've not same result on Android 8.1
In Android 8.1 app start first time with empty rl list and servise don't start correctly. If i restart the app with not empty rl list service start correctly, but then if i restart the app again with empty rl list foregruond service icon does not disappear.